# Showing an Ideal is the ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> If A is an Ideal of a ring R and the unity 1 belongs to A, prove that A=R.

It is a sufficient condition to show that $A\subseteq R$ and $R\subseteq A$.

Indeed, it is trivial to see that $A\subseteq R$ by the Theorem of Ideal test. $A$ must be a non-empty subset of a ring R. Since $A$ is an Ideal of a ring R, it is true that $A$ is a non-empty subset of a ring R.

Now, $A\subseteq R$.

So every element a in A is also an element in R. 
Let $a = r \in R$

Then, $\left [ a\cdot r \right ]\equiv \bar{r} \in R$. 
Recall that for a ring R it is true that $\left ( R,+ \right )$ is Abelian so closure under addition follows. 
Indeed, $\bar{r} \in R.$

Thus, $R\subseteq A.$

And so, $A=R$.

Note that I have not utilised the unity. Potential error exists. 
Any help in the form of **Hint** is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $r\in R,$ and any $a\in I,$ we have $r.a\in I.$ Take $a=1.$ Then $r.1=r \in I;$ For any $r\in R.$

Comment: Suppose the unity 1 were not given, would my attempt be valid?

Comment: No. the part $R\subseteq A$ is not valid: Unclear for me what you wrote.

Comment: I should leave for now but it is necessary condition. after an hour if u still have problem with it i can help.

Comment: It is solved. Thanks

Comment: you're welcome.